# Run unit tests in IntelliJ IDEA from multiple modules together

Tags: testing, intellij-idea

How can I run all tests from two or more IDEA modules at once?

I'm using many modules and it is important to run all of the unit tests often and when I choose more than one folder to run, there's no 'run' option on the context menu any more.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**Best way way:** (edit after 3 years)

There is even a better way to achieve this. From the [JetBrains JUnit Run Configuration docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html#configTab):

1. Select menu "Run" → "Edit Configurations...". Click green plus in left top corner and select JUnit.
2. Select "Test kind" to "Pattern" and enter this regexp exactly as you see it: `^(?!.*IT$).*$` (it starts with caret `^` and ends with dollar `$`). This regexp says: *all tests that do not finish with IT in their name*.

   **Note:** The regexp will match against the qualified file names, making it easy to exclude by module/packages as well. If your integration tests are grouped in a package `com.me.integrationtests`, the regex to match everything not in this package would be `^(?!.*com\.me\.integrationtests.*).*$`.
3. Select "Search for tests" to "In whole project". Working directory should be set to top module working directory (it should be set by default).
4. Enter a Name for your test like "All Unit tests". I also prefer to  mark "Share" option so this configuration won't disappear later. Click Apply and OK.

You can experiment with this regexp to fit your needs.

**Original answer:**

It is doable, although it's not comfortable.

1. Select first module, right-click on `test/java` directory and "Run All Tests". It creates test configuration.
2. Select "Edit configurations" and check "Share" on newly created configuration so it will be saved.
3. Select second module, "Run All Tests" on it, and check "Share" on this configuration as well.
4. In "Before launch" section, click "+" and select "Run Another Configuration" and then select first module's configuration.

This way you run configurations in a sequence and every configuration gets a new tab. Still, better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks! By far the cleanest way. Wondering if there is any better way to achieve this after 3 years :)

Comment: Thanks! You saved my time and this is by far still the most clever way I can find of to resolve both multiple coverage report generation and unified  case runner problem **in one shot**.

Comment: I've just edited my anser with a better solution @CoderSpinoza

Comment: The updated version is **not so good**, if your test cases uses module specific resources during its run-time - I still prefer the original solution.

Comment: How do I get this configuration to respect my Gradle dependencies? Now, it fails on missing classes from Guava. When running a single module's tests, it works fine.

Comment: Not sure why the `IT` is in the regex. For me the following works: `^(.*Test).*$`

Comment: @TomaszKalkosiński may be you know the way to exclude tests located in a certain class with the pattern? Or exclude a certain tests category. I have unit tests (inherited from a parent class marked with category) and integration tests, and I want to exclude the latter.

Comment: Late to the party but @nhaarman IT would stand for IntegrationTest(s) a different category of testing that you likely run separate from your Unit Tests and with different requirements/set up.

Comment: @indivisible Ah, thanks! That convention wasn't clear for me and didn't really become clear from the answer itself :)

Comment: On Android Studio 4.1 RC3, when I run the configuration it starts in the background and nothing ever shows up afterwards.

Answer (score 34):

Select all modules, right-click them and choose to run all tests. This will create a configuration called **"Whole Project"** which you can run again at any time.

I found this better than the accepted answer because this runs the unit tests separately for each module.  If your test cases use module-specific resources during its run-time then the accepted answer's best way won't work.

Select all modules

[image: Select all modules]

Right click and choose to run all tests

[image: Right click and choose to run all tests]

Get a new run configuration

[image: Get a new run configuration]

Comment: It is enough to select more than one module in the first step.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer.
The only reservation I have is the use of the term "easiest".
Unfortunately there is nothing easy about run configurations with Intellij.
There are many ways to do simple tasks with configurations and usually only one, if any work. So your task is often to iterate through all the different options searching for the one that works. Not easy at all.

Comment: This runs _all_ the tests in the project (Whole project), even though I'm selecting a small fraction of the modules. This is not what I want. In my case all the modules I want to run tests for share a common package, so I'm able to edit the resulting 'Whole project' configuration and add the Package, which filters to run the test only for the subset of modules.

Comment: with selecting whole project we cant run with project hence this cannot be a accepted answer

Answer (score 23):

You have to create a "Run Configuration":

1. Go to the dropdown on the top, at the right hand of the "Make" button and click on it
2. Select "Edit Configurations"
3. Now click on the "+" button to add a new run configuration and select JUnit
4. Then, when configuring the "Run Configuration", you'll find a "Test Kind" dropdown, select "All classes in directory"
5. Select the directory you want to use as the root, you can choose the top level directory for your project or any of the directories for your modules.
6. Select the IntelliJ module from where picking up the classpath (it can be the top level project if it has a classpath)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though it doesn't solve the problem. The perfect way would be to select several dirs, not only one. The pertial solution is to use patterns, but still may only pattern the package, not the dirs...

Comment: In "Test Kind" choose "All in package" and then choose the checkbox "In whole project". That will run tests in all Modules.

Comment: I would like each module to run with its own module dir as the working directory - that doesn't seem to be possible it seems to use a single module dir for the whole thing.

Comment: @MartinOdhelius that's the cleanest solution so far

Answer (score 5):

For me both solutions didn't work or didn't work es expected.

For me I have 3 modules. My modules dependencies look like this

**Presentation** -> **Domain** -> **Data**

I just wanted to execute all tests together. So I came up with the 'Across module dependencies' approach

My Settings look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me for a project with multiple modules.

Create a new JUnit run/debug configuration.
Test kind: 'All in package'
Search for tests: 'Whole project'

You will have to specify a working directory as well.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another not so obvious case is when code coverage is needed on more than one project.  The naive solution would be to select multiple projects and run all unit tests in them at once.  As it turns out, unit tests may fail if the classpath changes and IntelliJ has exactly one classpath entry per run configuration. In this case, running unit tests on projects sequentially is actually sufficient.  That's because at the end of each run IntelliJ (2017.2.5 Community Edition) asks if the collected coverage should replace or should be added to previously collected coverage stats.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gradle and have multiple modules, you can do it that way:

- make sure IntelliJ is set to use Gradle to run the tests (`Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Build Tools/Gradle` -> `Run tests using: Gradle`)
- right click over a module in the Project navigator and select `Run test in [module name]`
- once done, left click on the configuration that was created in the top toolbar and select `Edit Configurations...`
- in the Run field, simply add more modules just after the first one, for example, if you want to run tests in modules foo, bar and baz: `:foo:test :bar:test :baz:test --tests *`
- rename the configuration, for example `Test Foo + Bar + Baz`

Now you can just run the configuration to perform the tests you need.