# IntelliJ does not refresh Spring autoconfigurations in multi-module tests when running all tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I have a multi-module Maven project with three modules `A`,`B`,`C`, all of them are Spring-Boot modules.

- `B` is an autoconfiguration class, uses `A`. It has a conditional on a certain bean.
- `C` is also an autoconfiguration class, uses A as well, it doesn't have any conditionals because it's a very small module, and if you put it in your pom, you want the autoconfiguration.

When running the tests:

- `mvn clean install` works and everything passes.
- When I run the JUnit tests of each *individual* module from Intellij, everything also passes.

The problem is that when I try to run all the tests from IntelliJ, module `A` (the one that does not depend on anything) fails because it claims it cannot find a bean that module `C` needs! I can't even exclude the autoconfiguration because module `A` has no dependency on `C` so it doesn't know the class.

Anything that I am missing regarding how IntelliJ loads the context when you have autoconfigurations?

Comment: What run configuration do you use? What is the exact error? Could be related to how the classpath is configured. Normally the IDE uses the classpath of the module specified in Run/Debug Configurations | **Use classpath of module** of JUnit Run Configuration (if you use JUnit Configuration).

Comment: This sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-222014 report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for posterity. **This is a partial answer that assumes that all your modules share the same root package**. In my case, all the modules share `a.b.c` where the first module's package is `a.b.c.first`, the second module is `a.b.c.second` and so on. **If you have a better solution I'll happily change the accepted answer.**

The problem, as suspected, is how you define the test configuration. Since this is a multi-module project, and I want all the tests to run, there are two ways of defining it:

**The problematic way:** Defining a pattern on the entire project. This solution is described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17678240/503397).

[image: running all tests with a pattern]

Running this configuration will cause the problems described in the question - unrelated auto-configurations of dependencies the module doesn't have will start to fail and therefore the tests will fail as well.

**The way that works:** This way works under the said assumption that all modules share the same package. Create a new Run Configuration as follows:

[image: run all tests under a shared package]

- **Test kind:** All in package
- **Package:** The share root package of all your modules, e.g. `a.b.c` in the example I gave in the beginning of this answer.
- **Search for tests:** In whole project

This will run all your tests with the correct auto-configurations.